# PHP/MySQL Fatal memory allocation error

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting the `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)` error on this line:

```
$stmt -> bind_result($title, $author, $contents, $date, $image, $status);
```

of a mysqli/php statement, the query is a select statement that gets 1 row of text from a database, does anyone know whats gone wrong?

Full (and only) function on this page:

```
function get_selected_article($post_type, $post_id, $post_name)
{
    $con = new mysqli("---my ip---", "---my user---", "---my pass---", "---my database---");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "A problem has occurred";
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = $con -> prepare("SELECT `title`, `author`, `content`, `date`, `image`, `status` FROM ---my table--- WHERE `id` = ? AND `type` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC"))
{
    $stmt -> bind_param("is", $post_id, $post_type); // "i" for int
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($title, $author, $contents, $date, $image, $status);

    while ($stmt -> fetch())
    {
        echo "<table class = 'single_article_table'>";
        echo "<tr><td align='left'>".$date."</td><td align='left'>".$post_type."</td><td align='right'>".$author."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".$title."</a></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>".$content."</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }

    $stmt -> close();
}

    $con -> close();
}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: how many rows are you expecting!

Comment: trying to allocate 4gig? that's a bit much... What exactly is in this `image` field? a blob, or just a url to an on-disk file?

Comment: What is the format of the data you're trying to retreive? Are the image a blob?

Comment: @GrizzlyRawrz - can you try without the image?

Comment: @Marc B trying to get 1 field, and the image field is a VARCHAR link

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan tried without the image, same error

Comment: There are only 2 rows in the database so there is no where near enough data to be requiring this kind of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `content` column is LONGTEXT - "A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 – 1) characters." from the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem by changing the `content` field in the database to `mediumtext`rather than `longtext`.